# Weird error with MySQLi fetch_all

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

*This is probably going to be marked as a duplicate but my error seems to be different from the others that I've seen here on stackoverflow.*

**the following code is supposed to display the content from the image:
code:**

```
 if($news_result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY `likes` DESC LIMIT 4")) {                      
    if ($news_result->num_rows) {
        $rows = $news_result->fetch_all(MYSQL_ASSOC);
            $row_count = 0;
            foreach($rows as $row) {
                $row_count++;

                $content_echo = '
                    <div class="row inside" style="width: 99%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                    <a href="http://portuguesegaming.com/post/'.$row['url'].'">
                    <div class="view third-effect"
                            style="
                                background: url(../images/'.$background.'.png);
                                background-size:80%;
                                background-position: center;
                                margin-right: auto;
                                margin-left: auto;">    
                            <h3>'.$row['title'].'</h3><br>
                            <table style="width: 78%;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <h4 style="font-size: 12px;">'.$row['description'].'</h4>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <h4>BY: '.$row['creator'].'</h5>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <div class="likes" style="margin-top: -20px;"><div class="likes-icon"></div><h4>'.$row['likes'].'</h4></div>
                            <div class="mask">
                                <h6>READ MORE</h6>  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>';

                $separator = '  <br>
                <div class="separator" style="
                        margin-bottom: -25px;
                        margin-top: -25px;
                        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(254, 254, 254, 0), rgba(254, 254, 254, 0.75), rgba(254, 254, 254, 0));"></div>
                <br>';

                if ($news_result->num_rows > 1 && $row_count > 0 && $row_count < $news_result->num_rows) {
                    $content_echo .= $separator;
                }
                echo $content_echo;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Image:** [image]

This works on my wamp server, but when I upload the files to godaddy's host I got the error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all() in /home/ipsyko/public_html/index.php on line 102` which I read about it and they said its because of the PHP version, the goddady's PHP version is **5.4(native)** and it appears the error, I changed to normal **4.4(not native)** and the error didn't appear but also the content I wanted didn't appear which is weird, then I changed to **5.5** and happened the same thing that was happening in the **5.4 not native**, I even checked the **"mysqlnd"** option and nothing works.
Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Wow, that's weird since that function is available since PHP 5.3... but the error is clear, the method is undefined. Try with `fetch_array()` just to see what happens and then let's find out why it is undefined.

Comment: By the way, add mysqli/mysql tags so that more people can find your question!

Comment: @Zeke with `fetch_array()` I got an even weird result http://i.imgur.com/lgBlXPD.png

Comment: I see... I would code it very very differently but I don't want to waste your time changing your structure... one thing is you don't have to count your rows, use `$row_count = $news_result->num_rows;` instead. Also, with `fetch_array()` don't use `MYSQLI_ASSOC`, by default it will use `MYSQLI_BOTH`, so try with that.

Comment: Well... I'm just assuming you are using MySQLi, right? It won't be *too* important for your code, but I'd like to know so I can help better.

Comment: @Zeke yes I actually don't know much about MySQLi but since it started to say that MySQL was deprecated I had to change everything to MySQLi and somehow worked well on wamp server.

Comment: Well, yes, it actually is deprecated. It's been a long time now, we all use MySQLi or PDO. Anyway, that's a story for another day. What could you find using `MYSQLI_BOTH`?

Comment: OH WAIT. Look at your code! It says `MYSQL_ASSOC`.... you are missing the `I` for `MYSQLI`. Try that with `fetch_all()`!

Comment: @Zeke it is still doing the same thing if I use `fetch_array` even with `MySQLI_BOTH` it appears those weird results and if I use `fetch_all()` even with `MySQLI_ASSOC` I get the error, I think I should re-write the code for this section.

Comment: I see I see... do you mind showing me a little bit more of your entire source code? Of course, strip out anything server-related. Maybe I can check it out entirely and find what's going on... but I must admit I prefer procedural style over object-oriented.

Comment: Also, I can try it out on my own server and see if the problem is just the GoDaddy server....

Comment: @Zeke I placed the full code of this section of my website here: https://codeshare.io/2Dq2o I can actually send you the really full code if you want, btw thanks for the help and sorry for making you waste your time with me.

Comment: I see it... don't worry, I'm not wasting my time if I am helping you. I'm only wasting time if I don't solve your problem. It's 2:23AM and I'm tired but still, there must be a very stupid reason for this function to be undefined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98458/discussion-between-user3783087-and-zeke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code will work:

```
<?php
$news_result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY `likes` DESC LIMIT 4");
if(mysqli_num_rows($news_result) >= 1){
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($news_result)){

    switch($row['type']){
      case "global":$background = "globalnews";
        break;
      case "console":$background = "console_bg";
        break;
      case "pc":$background = "pc_bg";
        break;
      case "bar":$background = "bar_bg";
        break;
      default:$background = "";
    }

    $content_echo = '<div class="row inside" style="width: 99%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
      <a href="http://portuguesegaming.com/post/'.$row['url'].'">
        <div class="view third-effect" style="background: url(../images/'.$background.'.png); background-size:80%; background-position: center; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;">    
          <h3>'.$row['title'].'</h3>
          <table style="width: 78%;">
            <tr>
              <td><h4 style="font-size: 12px;">'.$row['description'].'</h4></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2"><h4>BY: '.$row['creator'].'</h4></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <div class="likes" style="margin-top: -20px;"><div class="likes-icon"></div><h4>'.$row['likes'].'</h4></div>
          <div class="mask">
            <h6>READ MORE</h6>  
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>';

    $separator = '<div class="separator" style="margin-bottom: -25px; margin-top: -25px; background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(254, 254, 254, 0), rgba(254, 254, 254, 0.75), rgba(254, 254, 254, 0));"></div>';
    echo $content_echo.$separator;
  }
}   
?>
```